# Is "Scope chain" in java script a pointer.?

Tags: javascript

Since in JavaScript primitives will not change their value, I inherited them in one function block, found this answer and I also inherited the objects and the values of that object got changed and came to know that primitives do not change their values but objects do. So, can we say a scope chain is, in fact, a pointer to variable objects?

Comment: can you give a sample code as to how you came to this conclusion ?

Comment: What do you call a "scope chain"? What do you mean by "I inherited them*? Not a great English speaker myself, but I think that sentence would mean they now belong to you because before your parents owned them. I guess it's not what you wanted to say.